# How to test one image in keras and output the prediction with its name

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have managed to train images with labels but i'm not able to predict a single image with the respective image and output it.

Here is the code:

```
labels = ['Black_Shank', 'Brown_Spot']
img_size = 224

def get_data(data_dir):
    data = []
    for label in labels:
        path = os.path.join(data_dir, label)
        class_num = labels.index(label)
        for img in os.listdir(path):
            try:
                img_arr = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img))[...,::-1] #convert BGR to RGB format
                resized_arr = cv2.resize(img_arr, (img_size, img_size)) # Reshaping images to preferred size
                data.append([resized_arr, class_num])
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
    return np.array(data)

train = get_data('/Users/cynthianchabaya/Downloads/Tobacco/Basedata/Training')
val = get_data('/Users/cynthianchabaya/Downloads/Tobacco/Basedata/Testing')

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32,3,padding="same", activation="relu", input_shape=(224,224,3)))
model.add(MaxPool2D())

model.add(Conv2D(32, 3, padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPool2D())

model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPool2D())
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(2, activation="softmax"))

model.summary()

#opt = Adam(lr=0.000001)
model.compile(optimizer = "adam" , loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True) , metrics = ['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs = 500 , validation_data = (x_val, y_val))

acc = history.history['accuracy']
val_acc = history.history['val_accuracy']
loss = history.history['loss']
val_loss = history.history['val_loss']

epochs_range = range(500)

predictions = model.predict_classes(x_val)
predictions = predictions.reshape(1,-1)[0]
print(classification_report(y_val, predictions, target_names = ['Black_Shank (Class 0)','Brown_Spot (Class 1)']))
```

I followed some tutorials, I don't quite understand it, but its working. lol.

Comment: You should load one image using `cv2.imread` then feed it to `model.predict_classes()`

Comment: You don't need `from_logits = True`, set it to `False`.

Answer (score 0):

First since you have a sofmax activation function you should not set from_logits=True in your loss function. Next issue is was your model trained on RGB or BGR images? The image you want to predict must be in the same format that the images were when you trained your model. I will assume it was trained on RGB images since you used cv2 to read in your images but converted to RGB.
Also did you train your model with scaled images? Usually they are scaled so the pixels are in the range from 0 to 1. Like image=image/255 but I did not see any rescaling in your code. Also the image must have the same shape as the training images which in your case looks like 224 X 224

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
RGB=True # set to false if trained on BGR images
Scaled=False # set to False if your training images were not scaled
filepath=r' put the path here of the file you want to predict'
image=cv2.imread(fpath)
if RGB:
    image=cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
image=cv2.resize(image, (224,224))
if scaled:
    image=image/255 # or whatever scale factor was used if any
image=np.expand_dims(image, axis=0) #input shape needs to be (1,width,height,channels)
predictions=model.predict(image) # prediction shape will be (1,2)
class_index-np.argmax(predictions)
```

class_index is the integer code for the predicted class in your case a 0 or a 1